# Show div on click of another div - not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make div .PA show when clicking on #toggle_pa and make it all save, but it won't work.

I don't know what to edit.

```
var $content0 = $('.PA');

if (localStorage.getItem('isVisible') === 'true') {
    $content0.addClass('pa_visible');
    $content0.removeClass('pa_content');
}

$('#toggle_PA').on('click', function() {
    $content0.toggleClass('pa_visible');
    $content0.addClass('pa_content');
    localStorage.setItem('isVisible', $content0.hasClass('pa_visible'));
});
```

Full code:
https://codepen.io/mSyx/pen/yWGxNZ

Here, clicking on #toggle_PA won't do anything.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the console of the codepen:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Adding this code into the top of your html made the pen work and do as expected:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```